# The operator && is undefined for the argument String,boolean on JAVA?

Tags: java

I'm a junior java Developer, entrusted with a Java Tool.

I have the following problem:

This tool takes in input 2 CSV files with specific fields.
The tool then generates 2 csv files as Output. First and Second Output.
Both Output files have the same fields, the first Output is based on some conditions and the second output on some other.

These 2  Output files contain different reconciliations for some data.Some records of the file have the same ID.

Example:

```
record1 = ID10-name One, 
record2 = ID10-Blue Two, 
record3 = ID10-name Three
```

One of the conditions is as follows:

```
if (line.getName (). toLowerCase (). contains ("Blue" .toLowerCase ())
|| line.getName (). equalsIgnoreCase ("Orange")) {
return true;
```

The method who implement this is  a boolean  ,and all the logic of the tool it's based on  this logic.The tool scrolls/processing  line by line .

```
  Iterator <BaseElaboration> itElab = result.iterator ();
    while (itElab.hasNext ()) {
    BaseLine Processing = itElab.next ();
```

On the SECOND OUTPUT file,I find a line/record  that has the name beginning with Blue.The tool rightly, it takes the line and inserts it in the Second Output File,cause all record who has name (getName), with Blue or Orange go on it
I should instead clump all the lines for the same ID even if only one of them has the name with blue.
Currently the tool do this :

**FIRST FILE OUTPUT**

```
record1 = ID10-name 
record3 = ID10-name Three
```

**SECOND FILE OUTPUT**

```
record2 = ID10-Blue Two
```

The expected output is

**FIRST FILE OUTPUT**

nothing cause one of the group of IDs,cointains a name with Blue

**SECOND FILE OUTPUT**

```
record1 = ID10-name
record2 = ID10-Blue Two
record3 = ID10-name Three
```

i think something like this,but doesnt work

```
if (line.getID() && line.getCollector().toLowerCase().contains("Blue".toLowerCase())
                    || line.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("black")) {
                return true;
```

How to group in java lines for lined  for the same ID,and do the esclusione on the noutput

CODE

Output

```
private void creaCSVOutput() throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException, ParseException {
        Writer writerOutput = new FileWriter(pathOutput);
        Writer writerEsclusi = new FileWriter(pathOutputEsclusi);

        StatefulBeanToCsv<BaseElaborazione> beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<BaseElaborazione>(writerOutput)
                .withSeparator(';').withQuotechar('"').build();

        StatefulBeanToCsv<BaseElaborazione> beanToCsvEsclusi = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<BaseElaborazione>(writerEsclusi)
                .withSeparator(';').withQuotechar('"').build();

        beanToCsv.write(CsvHelper.genHeaderBeanBase());
        beanToCsvEsclusi.write(CsvHelper.genHeaderBeanBase());

        Iterator<BaseElaborazione> itElab = result.iterator();
        while (itElab.hasNext()) {
            BaseElaborazione riga = itElab.next();

some set if and condition  ecc




esclusi.add(riga);
                itElab.remove();
            }
        }

        for (BaseElaborazione riga : result) {
            if(riga.getNota() == null || riga.getNota().isEmpty()) {
                riga.setNota(mapNota.get(cuvNota.get(riga.getCuv())));
            }
            beanToCsv.write(riga);
        }

        for (BaseElaborazione riga : esclusi) {
            if(riga.getNota() == null || riga.getNota().isEmpty()) {
                riga.setNota(mapNota.get(cuvNota.get(riga.getCuv())));  
        }
            beanToCsvEsclusi.write(riga);
        }

        writerOutput.close();
        writerEsclusi.close();
    }
```

The method for the esclusi( 2 output)

```
 private boolean checkPerimetroJunk(BaseElaborazione riga) {

        if (riga.getMercato().toLowerCase().contains("Energia Libero".toLowerCase())) {
            if (riga.getStrategia().toLowerCase().startsWith("STRATEGIA FO".toLowerCase())
                    || (riga.getStrategia().toLowerCase().contains("CREDITI CEDUTI".toLowerCase())
                    || (riga.getAttivita().equalsIgnoreCase("Proposta di Recupero Stragiudiziale FO")
                    ||  (riga.getAttivita().toLowerCase().contains("Cessione".toLowerCase())
                    || (riga.getLegalenome().equalsIgnoreCase("Euroservice junk STR FO")
                    || (riga.getLegalenome().equalsIgnoreCase("Euroservice_FO"))))))) {

                    onlyCUV=true; 
                }

                     else if(Collections.frequency(storedIds,riga.getCuv()) >= 1 ){
                 onlyCUV = true;
                   }

        return onlyCUV;
    }
         else if (riga.getMercato().equals("MAGGIOR TUTELA")) {

                    if(riga.getCollector().toLowerCase().contains("Cessione".toLowerCase())
                    || (riga.getCollector().equalsIgnoreCase("Euroservice_Fo"))
                    || (riga.getAttivitaCrabb().toLowerCase().contains("*FO".toLowerCase())
                    ||  (riga.getaNomeCluster().equalsIgnoreCase("Full Outsourcing")))) {


                onlyCUV = true;
            }

             else if(Collections.frequency(storedIds,riga.getCuv()) >= 1 ){
                 onlyCUV = true;

        }

        return onlyCUV;
    }
        return false;
    }
```

WHERE riga=lines
cessione ecc are people who have black ecc its an example
Now the part of MAGGIOR TUTELA ITS WORKING,but not working the part of LIBERO.I dont know why.

Comment: Java and JavaScript have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Read something about booleans and boolean operators. They only operate on boolean arguments. I doubt that `line.getID()` returns a boolean.

Comment: its return a string.